# Laravel testing: check if a radio input with a specific value exists on a page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I was writing some integration tests for an app I'm working on for a client. They have a designer who's going to work on the HTML so our tests  have things like checking if a link exists, checking if a radio group has all the values we expect to have etc (This is so that after the designer gives us edits we can make sure by way of tests that he didn't mistakenly change some of the things he wasn't supposed to change).

So say we have a radio input for *gender*, we'd want to check if the input values *male* and *female* exist so naturally I wrote something like:

```
$this->visit('/auth/register')
    ->select('male', 'sex');
```

..expecting this to fail if there wasn't a radio input of name 'sex' with value 'male'. So looking at the Laravel source I'm seeing that's not the philosophy behind ->select(), it simply stores a value to some internal `$inputs` variable meaning this also would fail:

```
$this->visit('/auth/register')
    ->select('male', 'sex');
    ->seeIsSelected('sex', 'male');
```

Question is there a way using the functionality built-in to run such a test, I guess to arrive at the intended use of `->select($value, $option)` where it would fail if in the view there isn't a radio or select input with that combination of $value and $option?

PS: I'm aware of, and have as a last resort, the `->see("type='radio' value='male')` method

Comment: what would you like to use? And is "see" doing what you're after?

Comment: I think you're going to need a custom function for that if `see()` is not good enough

Comment: You're right. Ended up rolling something custom, but the in-built ones can come close (if you can check in the answer below). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems there isn't a way in the default assertions to do this. The closest in functionality were the `seeInField()` & `seeIsSelected()` but they don't do exactly what I wanted. One solution (which can be edited to suit your assertion tastes) is:

```php
$this->assertCount(1, $this->visit('/auth/register')
    ->crawler->filter('input[name="sex"][value="female"]'));
```

The other solution is a custom assertion like Joshua Pendo advised.